# How to put a background image on GridBagLayout

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I am trying to work with layout managers for the first time, and they are just kicking me in the teeth. I am trying to make a background image and then put buttons on top, using GridBagLayout, if there is a a better layoutmanager please do tell. As for trying to learn how to use layout managers, its very difficult and any learning references would also be much appreciated.
[image: This is whats it looks like currently]
This is what it looks like currently,
I can get the frame to show the full image, but when i use gridlayout manager, it does that

```
public void addComponentsToPane(Container pane){
    BackgroundImage image = new BackgroundImage();
    JButton button1, button2, button3, button4, button5;
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    if(shouldFill){
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    }   
    button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    }
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    button1.setOpaque(false);
    pane.add(button1, c);


    button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;    
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    button2.setOpaque(false);
    pane.add(button2, c);

    button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    button3.setOpaque(false);
    pane.add(button3, c);

    button4 = new JButton("Long-Named Button 4");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(button4, c);
    button5 = new JButton("button 1");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.ipady = 0;       //reset to default
    c.weighty = 1.0;   //request any extra vertical space
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END; //bottom of space
    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);  //top padding
    c.gridx = 1;       //aligned with button 2
    c.gridwidth = 2;   //2 columns wide
    c.gridy = 2;       //third row
    pane.add(button5, c);
    c.ipadx = 800;
    c.ipady = 400;
    pane.add(image, c);

}
```

[image: This is what i'm trying to get it to look like]
This is what i'm trying to make it look like

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to do it: using a JLabel as a container with an image (it's a bit unusual but actually works pretty well):

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestBackgroundImage {

    private static final String BACKHGROUND_IMAGE_URL = "http://www.okyn.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/League_of_Legends.jpeg";

    protected void initUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestBackgroundImage.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final ImageIcon backgroundImage = new ImageIcon(new URL(BACKHGROUND_IMAGE_URL));
        JLabel mainPanel = new JLabel(backgroundImage) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
                Dimension lmPrefSize = getLayout().preferredLayoutSize(this);
                size.width = Math.max(size.width, lmPrefSize.width);
                size.height = Math.max(size.height, lmPrefSize.height);
                return size;
            }
        };
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            mainPanel.add(new JButton("Button " + (i + 1)), gbc);
        }
        // Let's put a filler bottom component that will push the rest to the top
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        mainPanel.add(Box.createGlue(), gbc);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new TestBackgroundImage().initUI();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And the result:

[image]

- `GridBagLayout` is unable to handle layering of components (so if you have overlapping `gridx`/`gridy` pairs, it won't handle it as layering, I would think that the output is pretty much undetermined.
- Try to avoid using `gridx/gridy` as it make a code hard to maintain. Playing with relative values on `gridwidth/gridheight` is much easier to maintain.

Comment: What is the reason for Overriding mainPanel, getPreferredSize method?
Is this an efficient solution? Also what are insets?

Comment: The component is really serving two purposes, 1) to display an image and 2) as a container to hold various components. So the preferred size of the component has been modified to use the largest values of height or width from the preferred size of either 1, or 2.

Comment: @Loligans Reason for override prefsize: see camickr explanation (yes it is efficient). Insets is the external padding of the component (see `GridBagConstraint` javadoc).

Comment: -1 for mis-using the (near-) accidental container-ness of a JSomething

Comment: @kleopatra that's a pretty personnal opinion which is only subject to debate and no clear facts to support this. I've seen many experienced Swing developers using it (include HFOE, camickr, ...).

Comment: even experienced developers can do stuff incorrectly - myself included, of course :-) IMO, they should not spread corner cases that will break at the slightest breeze: it's unspecified how a "leaf" component like a label will behave in a role as container - f.i. if/how it will respect the layoutManager is a lucky accident.

Comment: @kleopatra _even experienced developers can do stuff incorrectly_ agreed. My understanding is that `JComponent` and alls its children inherit of `Container` and therefore they respect its javadoc: _A generic Abstract Window Toolkit(AWT) container object is a component that can contain other AWT components._ So I feel that, on the contrary, the fact they respect the LayoutManager is everything but a "lucky" accident. As I said, this is subject to debate. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for a couple of solutions depending on your requirement:

1. Use a JLabel for painting the image at its actual size.
2. Use the BackgroundPanel to allow for scaling of the background image.